# Would Nova Squadron have been punished if their stunt succeeded?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the TNG episode "The First Duty," an inquiry is made into a shuttle crash that resulted in the death of a member of Nova Squadron, a group of elite Starfleet cadets. Eventually it is revealed that the crash was the result of Nova Squadron attempting a shuttle maneuver called the Kolvoord Starburst, which, while spectacular if performed correctly, had been banned for decades after an accident resulting in the loss of five cadets.

Had Nova Squadron executed the starburst successfully and no one died, would they have been acclaimed for it, or would they have gotten in trouble for attempting a banned stunt?

Comment: There's no way to answer hypotheticals like that.  The most anyone can do is make a case that Starfleet had corrupt leadership so anything could happen.

Comment: @DavidW- I'm assuming you were being sarcastic, but edited the question just in case.

Comment: @Nu'Daq I don't know if I was being sarcastic as much as merely unhelpfully literal. :)  But I do appreciate the clarified rewording. :)

Comment: It would be akin to setting off a spectacular but illegal firework display, where no one got hurt. You'd probably still get arrested & punished but you'd still get the kudos of your compatriots. Locarno probably respects the approval of his peers more than the stuffy Academy bosses (Principal? Dean?) and so would be happy to take whatever punishment he got if it came with the admiration of all the lads.

Comment: Not sure how this is opinion-based when there is an answer from in-universe - "_If it worked [...]_"

Comment: @fez In-universe speculation, "thinks", opinion, and hypotheticals are not facts in-universe or out and don't become facts just because they are in-universe. Picard correctly guessing what is going on in a cadet's head says nothing about what will actually be done by an Admiral in charge of the academy.  Nor did Picard discuss what an Admiral would actually do.  There's a lesson in the episode that what cadets think are facts and good ideas are clearly not.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - it's not an opinionated answer though. Just because the answer is *an opinion in-universe*, it doesn't make the answer itself an opinion because, quite literally, it is stating from canon

Answer (score 3):

Obviously we can't definitively say what would have happened (since it didn't happen), but we do get Picard's thoughts on what he *thinks* would occur.

He seems fairly convinced that the assembled crowd at the commencement, which would obviously include all of the Academy bigwigs, would have been very surprised at seeing this banned maneuver being performed, but the thrill of seeing them perform it *successfully* would have staved off any significant punishment, at least to the point that it would allow Locarno to graduate.

> **PICARD:** *I think that Nicholas Locarno wanted to end his Academy career in a blaze of glory. That he convinced the four of you to learn the Kolvoord Starburst for the commencement demonstration. **If it worked, you would thrill the assembled guests and Locarno would graduate as a living legend.** Only it didn't work, and Joshua Albert paid the price. Am I correct? Cadet, I asked you a question. Am I correct?*
>
> [TNG: The First Duty](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/219.htm)

That being said, in this particular instance they were *practicing* the maneuver in what they thought was a blind spot. Had they been successful, no-one would have been any the wiser. Indeed, this may not even be the first time they'd attempted it.

Comment: PIcard does not think that.  At most one can say Picard thinks that Locarno thinks that it would result in Locarno being a living legend.  And that still doesn't rule out a punishment even in Locarno's mind - just that the benefit would exceed the cost.  Otherwise everytime Columbo came up with a murder motive Valorum would say Columbo thinks that too.  (Picard may or may not - but he's clearly being hypothetical to establish motive.)

Comment: @lucasbachmann - If this was a court of law, I'd  demand that the judge formally accept Picard as an expert witness on what the Academy bigwigs would or would not do.

Comment: If I were Wesley in a court of law I would state that I cannot assign truth values to hypothetical audience reactions.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - I've edited to reflect your concern. Picard definitely seems to think that Locarno would have still been allowed to graduate, so I've restricted the specualtion to that and that alone.

Comment: I think the big question is whether, when Picard says "If it worked, you would thrill the assembled guests and Locarno would graduate as a living legend", he's saying what he actually thinks would have happened, or if he's still just describing what he suspects that Locarno told the cadets when "he convinced the four of you". If the latter, then the statement tells us nothing about what Picard would say the actual likely result would have been, if he was called as an expert witness and asked about that.

Answer (score -1):

I think they would have all received a [formal reprimand](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Formal_reprimand). That seems to be the typical punishment for improper conduct that doesn't end in catastrophe.  In the episode, the cadets were going to get a just a reprimand before Wesley admitted to the plan.  It would have appeared on their records but not resulted in any meaningful damage to their careers.